# My code is showing error during Exception handling

Tags: python-3.x, oop

I have written this code by defining instSet() class (This code inserts element to list using insert() method and then performs various functions such as removing an element using remove() method by checking if the element is present, if not, raises an expetion:

```
class instSet(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.vals = []

    def insert(self, e):
        if not e in self.vals:
            self.vals.append(e)

    def remove(self, e):
        try:
            self.vals.remove(e)
        except:
            raise ValueError(str(e) + ' not found')

    def member(self, e):
        return e in self.vals

    def __str__(self):
        self.vals.sort()
        result = ''
        for e in self.vals:
            result = result + str(e) + ','
        return '{' + result[:-1] + '}'
```

Some expression performed are:

```
a = instSet()
a.insert(1)
a.remove(3)
print(a)
```

Main problem is when I am trying to remove an element which is not present in the list it is throwing error like this:

```
ValueError: list.remove(x): x not in list
```

Insted it should return:

```
ValueError: 3 not found
```

What is wrong in the above code?

Answer (score 0):

There is issue with valueError that you used in except. Try using below code

```
except:
  raise Exception(str(e) + ' not found') from None
```

Comment: Still showing default error message: Traceback (most recent call last):

Comment: Then don't raise the exception, Just use print(str(e) + ' not found') in except block

Comment: Mark it as answer it is solved your problem.